# How to find the greatest difference between cells in different rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table A which stores a sequence of numbers and timestamps

```
value    timestamp
12087    2012-01-01 00:00:00
12110    2012-01-02 02:00:00
12223    2012-01-04 03:00:00
12312    2012-01-04 05:00:00
12387    2012-01-04 06:00:00
12388    2012-01-05 01:11:23
...
```

The both values and timestamps are ordered: the greater timestamp the greater value, but there is no other dependency between them.

I need to find the greatest difference between values in sorted sequence for a period. In the example the differences are:

```
12110-12087=23
12223-12100=13
12312-12223=89
12387-12312=75
12388-12387=1
```

So we have the greatest difference 89.

The question is: how to code SQL query for that? Do know, that I don't want to use full product and/or correlated queries since the table is enormous.

Comment: Expand your question to specify wether you need to know or not, which values contributed to the greatest difference.

Comment: Does order matter? So you only compare the difference between one row and the next? In relational tables, order doesn't mean anything so you may be hard pressed to do this in SQL alone. Procedural logic may do what you want.

Comment: Also - what is enormous? Anything less than several million rows is small...

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan: I don't need the values, just the difference.

Comment: @NWest: Each period has at least 5mln rows.

Comment: LAG functions work for this - although not sure if those are supported in mysql.  otherwise it will be a correlated subquery to find the max that is < current date

Comment: Just to be clear, you need the greatest difference between any 2 values, for a period (not all values in the period). Is your table data dynamic, does it change over time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    (case when (@prev is null) then 0
    else abs(value - @prev) end) as diff
  , concat(value, '-', @prev)
  , @prev := value

    from (select value, dt from table1 order by dt) ordered
    order by diff limit 1
```

add the period restrictors into the from subquery

edit, new info tells me this is an unreliable method
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html (<kbd>ctrl + f</kbd> for `SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1`)

Comment: This is dangerous to do in MySQL. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html - "As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement."

Comment: @NWest, thanks I didn't know that. They even specifically gave an example warning against what I did.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(result) 
from (
      select  ((select value 
                from Table t2 
                where t2.value > t1.value and t2.time <=  @PeriodEnd limit 1) 
      -  t1.value) as result 
      from Table t1
      where t1.value between @PeriodStart and @PeriodEnd
 ) as t where result is not null
```

Comment: A kind of correlated query. That's not what I want.